# API.ai intents not picking up Entities

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I first created 1 entity:

`@ordering-type`, then created 2 more `@ordering-size`, and `@ordering-topping`.

[image]

---

Then in my intents, when I'm creating user actions, it only picks up the $ordering-type, but not $ordering-size or $ordering-toppings.

You can see in the screenshots below that the keywords `small`, `medium` or `large` do not get highlighted, nor does `pepperoni` or `mushroom`.

[image]

[image]

Because of that, I cannot correctly create a dynamic response message.

What am I doing wrong here? Documentation and tutorials are very limited with Google Home.

[image]

---

**Ordering-size and Ordering-toppings entities:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show screen shots with the ordering-size and ordering-topiings entities as well? Or just what you see when you click on the Entities tab (which should list all your user defined Entities).

Comment: Have you tried selecting the text in the user-says prompts and then selecting the associated entity type?

Comment: @LeonNicholls has a good suggestion (and it should be added as an answer since it may help others), but it also shouldn't be necessary in this case. (At least it isn't in my testing so far.) So it sounds like something else is up.

Comment: @Prisoner heya! I just added screenshots of those entities at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @LeonNicholls That was it! Do you want to post your answer? I did not know you could do that, I just double clicked the text and all the options showed up

Comment: Something is up with the images - they're not showing. (But glad to hear Leon's suggestion worked!)

Comment: Please consider adding the answer in Answer and mark as answered.
I visited this same post much time considering it unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entity mappings aren't provided automatically, you can manually select the text in the user-says prompts and then select the associated entity type.